# Define transfer mode when trying to SFTP files using Python

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

We are trying to transfer text files from a Linux server to a Windows server using a python script (which resides on the SFTP server).

It is necessary for us to ensure the files are transferred using text mode. I don't see this possibility in `pysftp`. Is there any other Python library that supports this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pysftp/Paramiko uses an SFTP protocol version 3.

In the SFTP protocol version 3, there are no transfer modes. Or in other words, there is only the *binary* transfer mode.

Even if pysftp/Paramiko supported a newer version of SFTP, which do support the text/ascii mode, it is unlikely to help you. Most SFTP servers are OpenSSH. And OpenSSH uses SFTP 3 too.

See also [How to transfer binary file in SFTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29226647/850848)

---

If you need to convert the file to Windows format, you need to do it upfront, before a file transfer.

A naive implementation would be like:

```
WINDOWS_LINE_ENDING = b'\r\n'
UNIX_LINE_ENDING = b'\n'

with open("/local/path/file.txt", "rb") as local_file:
    contents = local_file.read()
    contents = contents.replace(UNIX_LINE_ENDING, WINDOWS_LINE_ENDING)
    with sftp.open("/remote/path/file.txt", "wb") as remote_file:
        remote_file.write(contents)
```

(conversion based on [How to convert CRLF to LF on a Windows machine in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36422107/850848))